# Hook_Form_Alter Edit Existing Field Type

Tags: forms

I am using hook_form_alter in template.php to add datepicker to a field on an exposed view filter.

```
function MYTHEME_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

  if($form_id == "views_exposed_form"){
    $form['data_2_op'] = array(
            '#type' => 'date_popup',
            '#date_format' => 'Y-m-d'
        );
    }
}
```

But all it is doing is adding another field into the form, rather than editing the field I have declared. Is there a way I can just add #type > 'date_popup' to an existing field?

EDIT:

Results after using...

```
drupal_set_message($form_id);  // print form ID to messages
  drupal_set_message(print_r($form, TRUE));  // print array to messages

views_exposed_form
Array ( 
  [#info] => Array ( 
    [filter-combine] => Array ( 
      [operator] => combine_op 
      [value] => combine 
      [label] => Search Event ID 
      [description] => 
    ) 
[filter-data_2] => Array ( 
  [operator] => data_2_op 
  [value] => data_2 
  [label] => Choose Date [description] => 
  )
[filter-data] => Array ( 
  [value] => data 
  [label] => Data field 
  [description] => ) 
  [filter-data_1] => Array ( 
    [value] => data_1 
    [label] => Data field 
    [description] => 
    ) 
  ) 
[combine] => Array ( 
  [#type] => textfield 
  [#size] => 30 
  [#default_value] => ) 
[data_2] => Array (
  [#type] => textfield 
  [#size] => 30 
  [#default_value] => )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) work only with module implementation. So you have to use it in any module not in template.php

Use the above statement in module like

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

  if($form_id == "views_exposed_form"){
    $form['data_2'] = array(
            '#type' => 'date_popup',
            '#date_format' => 'Y-m-d'
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Its working, its just adding another field rather than editing it. If i add this as a module, will it automatically edit the field instead?

Comment: Yeah i used drupal_set_message(print_r($form, TRUE)); to print an array and got the field name from there. It inserts the new datepicker field in between the data_2_op field and its label, instead of just altering it. I'll try it in a module to see if it makes a difference. Thanks.

Comment: Nope, That didn't work, putting it into a custom module did the exact same thing that it did in the template.php file.

Comment: Just updated it, its the second field in the exposed filter that Im looking to change.

Comment: I don't know why, but it has suddenly started working! Im using the exact same code I had to begin with, and I had already flushed the cache a few times. Oh well, at least it works! Thanks for you help